# Is there an Amazon AWS service we can leverage to detect correlation between two texts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlp

We're a database of Q&A from customers (much like StackOverflow :-P) and we're working on a bot to automatically identify the most likely response to a ticket being opened. e.g.

```
N;Q;A
1;how to recover my password?;Please go to https://.../resetPWD
2;which are the office hours?;office is open 9-13 and 14-18
```

Basically we want to create suggestions for customer care operators pointing them to known answers.

We're using Amazon AWS as a platform of choice and we'd like to offload this to existing APIs (rather then resorting to deploying a dedicated NPL solution).

**To be clear** we don't want to write/deploy any code, we just want to use AWS APIs/services

Is there any service which will automatically detect/classify the "most similar request" and allow us to provide suggestions? e.g. some kind of text correlation APIs?

e.g. something like

```
input: "I lost my password and need to recover it!"
response: "1;how to recover my password?;Please go to https://.../resetPWD"
```

Answer (score 1):

[AWS Comprehend](https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/) is very much what you are looking for in terms of natural language processing. You can create entire workflows from the console, no coding required.

Comment: We're been using AWS Comprehend for some time but I don't see a correlation service (maybe my fault). I see topi classification and entity extraction. Although these could be used as building blocks then I'd need to build taxonomies to group entities and some kind of metric te measure distances.
Anything I miss here?